# Asp .Net Core 3.1 return File from controller on new MS Edge takes forever to download

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

this is just a handler to download an excel of data that comes from database, i even tried use debugger and everything goes fine. On chrome or firefox it file appears on downloads as soon as i click the button, but on the new MS Edge, it takes from 10 to 20 or more seconds until it starts downloading? Why???

```
public async Task<FileResult> OnGetDownloadExcel(int id)
    {
        var inventarios = await _context.Localizations
                .Where(l => l.InventoryRecordId == id)
               .Select(ir => new
               {
                   ir.InventoryRecord.Id,
                   Armazem = ir.InventoryRecord.Warehouse.Name,
                   Colaborador = ir.InventoryRecord.User.Name,
                   ir.InventoryRecord.CreationDate,
                   ir.InventoryRecord.ClosedDate,
                   ir.InventoryRecord.Warehouse.Objective,
                   Resultado = (ir.InventoryRecord.Localizations.Sum(l => l.Precision) / ir.InventoryRecord.Localizations.Count()) * 100,
                   Localizacao = ir.Name,
                   ir.LabelsMissing,
                   ir.LabelsStored,
                   ir.Precision,
                   ir.Labels
               })
               .AsNoTracking()
               .ToListAsync();

        var comlumHeadrs = new string[]
         {
             "Id",
             "Armazém",
             "Colaborador",
             "Criado Em",
             "Finalizado Em",
             "Objectivo",
             "Resultado Final",
             "Localização",
             "Etiquetas Por Inventariar",
             "Etiquetas Inventariadas",
             "Precisão",
             "Referência",
             "Etiqueta Não Encontrada"
         };

        byte[] result;

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook

            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventário"); //Worksheet name
            using (var cells = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 13]) //(1,1) (1,6)
            {
                cells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            }

            //First add the headers
            for (var i = 0; i < comlumHeadrs.Count(); i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = comlumHeadrs[i];
            }

            //Add values
            var j = 2;
            foreach (var item in inventarios)
            {
                if (item.Labels.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var etiqueta in item.Labels)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[$"A{j}"].Value = item.Id;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"B{j}"].Value = item.Armazem;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"C{j}"].Value = item.Colaborador;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"D{j}"].Value = item.CreationDate.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
                        worksheet.Cells[$"E{j}"].Value = item.ClosedDate.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
                        worksheet.Cells[$"F{j}"].Value = item.Objective;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"G{j}"].Value = item.Resultado;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"H{j}"].Value = item.Localizacao;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"I{j}"].Value = item.LabelsMissing;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"J{j}"].Value = item.LabelsStored;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"K{j}"].Value = item.Precision * 100;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"L{j}"].Value = etiqueta.Reference;
                        worksheet.Cells[$"M{j}"].Value = etiqueta.Name;

                        j++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[$"A{j}"].Value = item.Id;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"B{j}"].Value = item.Armazem;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"C{j}"].Value = item.Colaborador;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"D{j}"].Value = item.CreationDate.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
                    worksheet.Cells[$"E{j}"].Value = item.ClosedDate.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
                    worksheet.Cells[$"F{j}"].Value = item.Objective;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"G{j}"].Value = item.Resultado;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"H{j}"].Value = item.Localizacao;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"I{j}"].Value = item.LabelsMissing;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"J{j}"].Value = item.LabelsStored;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"K{j}"].Value = item.Precision * 100;
                    worksheet.Cells[$"L{j}"].Value = "";
                    worksheet.Cells[$"M{j}"].Value = "";

                    j++;
                }
            }
            result = package.GetAsByteArray();
        }

        return File(result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml", $"inventario{id}.xlsx");
    }
```

**EDIT**

here is my edge version

> Version 80.0.361.66 (Official build) (64-bit)

either way, maybe this is not the right place to ask about this, but i don't know where can i report problems with Edge

this image is when i click the button, and the request is the last item at the bottom, as you can see there is no problem.

[image]

Comment: please specify your Edge version...

Comment: @Smankusors I posted it on the question

Comment: in edge, if you press F12 and look at the network traffic, do you see any delays?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this has anything to do with your .NET Core code or application in general. I have personally experienced the same thing you mentioned, for just about every download when using Edge. It takes about 10-20 seconds for the download to start. Is this the Chromium Edge that you are testing, or is it the old Edge ? The fact that other browsers work just fine, would indicate it's likely an Edge problem and not your app.

Comment: Have you checked browser settings? Microsoft likes to do that security stuff automatically.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-download-speed-is-really-slow/9d7297a8-2c13-48cc-9367-f177bd2091e7

Comment: @jandre it is the new edge

Comment: @Jackal If that's the case, then I would assume it's an Edge problem and not a you problem. You said it worked fine on Chrome and Firefox, which leads me to believe it's Edge doing additional things before downloading the file. For example, you can go into the privacy/security settings in Edge and you can modify the virus/malicious downloads checking it does. Those are all on by default.

Comment: @jandrew thanks it worked, i tried only disabling the tracking part but didn't do anything, at the bottom in privacy settings i disabled the defender smartscreen check and it's back to normal like in chrome.